# Changing New Mail Sound in macOS Sierra

Tags: mail.app, macos, audio, notifications

As of macOS Sierra, assigning a custom sound file in **Mail** no longer appears possible. All I get is “New Messages Sound” in addition to the old options:

[image: New Messages Sound]

Is there a way to assign a custom **Mail** sound in macOS Sierra, possibly via editing a plist?

The interesting thing is, I’ve logged into the **Guest** account, and even though the same option is selected, the sound that plays when a new mail comes in is the sound I had previously under MY user account. But I can’t seem to find where that sound file is assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your custom mail sounds to `~/Library/Sounds`. Then they’ll show up in the **Mail** preference pane.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Now if only those sounds would show up in **Messages** and **FaceTime** too…