# Finding Mac mail sounds plist

Tags: mail.app, email, plist

I have been trying on and off for a fair while to edit the default Mail.app system sounds from their defaults. Ideally I'd like access to all my system sounds eventually, but Mail.app seems like a good start.

A link [from LifeWire](https://www.lifewire.com/change-sounds-os-x-mail-1172742) shows that you can duplicate your mail app and then overwrite the names but it seems clunky to me - does anyone know where the plist is that activates the sounds for Mail.app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the 'new message sound' in the mail preferences, as well as disable other sounds (send message 'swoosh' etc.).  Granular control outside of that isn't possible via the GUI.  See screenshot.

As per here [Changing New Mail Sound in macOS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257089/changing-new-mail-sound-in-macos-sierra), you can copy custom sounds to ~/Library/Sounds and they will show up as an option to select in Mail preferences.

One could then programmatically use the *defaults* command  to select your custom sound via Terminal or script if you run the following command from within the folder "~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences":

```
defaults write com.apple.mail NewMessagesSoundName -string filename
```

where "filename" is the name of the file, without the extension, of what you copied to ~/Library/Sounds

[image]

Comment: Thanks, ideally I wanted to be able to manipulate all the default sounds via the terminal really

Comment: You should still be able to manipulate this via terminal 'defaults'l commands.  The .plist for mail is ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist - you'll see the keys that need be to changed for mail sounds if you open via xcode - but again, only the options shown above are what's changeable

Comment: Ok, is there literally no way to edit the file name of the sound it uses in the plist? Even when disabling csrutil?

Comment: the defaults write command will allow you to change the value.  Iplease see my example in the answer

Comment: You said "I am not sure if this would ultimately work but you can try!", well if you're not sure something works, then you probably shouldn't post it as part of the answer without first verifying whether or not it works! One thing is for sure though, it will not work if Mail is running.

Comment: Very helpful comment.  Does policy mandate that an suggestion cannot be made for OP to experiment on their own?...  Anyway I hope it now meets your editorial standards.  And BTW you don't need to quit Mail if you follow my instructions.

Comment: I appreciate the continued help from anyone on the topic as it is difficult to find answers to this problem in the current OSX version, I constantly get article after article about ~/library/sounds. The defaults command is very useful, however like you said received mail is the only editable value

Comment: Content of the answers should be accurate. Information you're not sure of should be placed in a comment. Since OS X Mountain Lion, `default write ...` commands made when an application is open typically do not take immediate effect and will be overwritten with the value already in memory when the application exits. This is true for the majority of applications however, there are exceptions and in some cases a secondary command must be issued immediate after. the `defaults write ...` command for the change to take  immediate effect.

Comment: Try and see.  In this case it takes effect immediately.  You are probably thinking of the method whereby modifying or replacing plist files required immediately performing a killall cfprefsd in order for values not to be overwrote by macos, as well as restarting your session/app.  defaults write takes care of modifying the file on disk, its cached memory version, and applying the new settings.